# scanf getting ignored when input is decimal

Tags: c

I am trying to create a total area calculator for total number rooms,
and here is my approach

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int main()
 {
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
 int odasayı = 0;
 double enin = 0, boy = 0, toplam = 0;

printf("Metrekare hesaplayıcıya hoşgeldiniz!\n\n"); //welcome 
message
printf("Lütfen oda sayısını giriniz:\n"); 
scanf("%d", &odasayı); //room number input


if (odasayı>=1)
{

    switch (odasayı)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("1 nolu odanın enini giriniz:\n"); //enter width
        scanf("%lf", &enin);
        printf("1 nolu odanın boyu giriniz:"); //enter length
        scanf("%lf", &boy);
        toplam = (enin * boy);
        printf("Evin toplam alanı %lf metrekaredir\n", toplam); 
        //total area
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("1 nolu odanın enini giriniz:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &enin);
        printf("1 nolu odanın boyu giriniz:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &boy);
        printf("2 nolu odanın enini giriniz:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &enin);
        printf("2 nolu odanın boyu giriniz:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &boy);
        toplam = enin * boy;
        printf("Evin toplam alanı %lf metrekaredir\n", toplam);
        break;
    
    case 3:
        printf("1 nolu odanın enini giriniz:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &enin);
        printf("1 nolu odanın boyu giriniz:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &boy);
        printf("2 nolu odanın enini giriniz:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &enin);
        printf("2 nolu odanın boyu giriniz:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &boy);
        printf("3 nolu odanın enini giriniz:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &enin);
        printf("3 nolu odanın boyu giriniz:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &boy);
        toplam = enin * boy;
        printf("Evin toplam alanı %lf metrekaredir\n", toplam);
        break;


    default:
    
        break;
    }
}
else
{
    printf("\nOda sayısı olarak en az 1 girmelisiniz\n\n\n\n");
} //If room number entered is less than 1 user receives this 
    message
```

In my assignment, I am asked to ask the user to input and integer that is equal to or larger than 1. If it less than one the user receives the "else" message.
The total number of rooms that I have in the assignment is 3. For each case the console is to print out "Please enter room # width" and "Please enter room # length" relative to the number of rooms given.

My problem is when I try to input a decimal in the first `scanf` function, the rest are ignored.
There are no restriction to how I would approach this problem and I chose to use `switch..case`.

Output should be like this

```
 Enter number of rooms 
 Enter room 1 width
 Enter room 1 height
 Total area is :
```

Instead I am getting this output:
Metrekare hesaplayiciya hosgeldiniz!

```
Please enter room number:
1
Enter room 1 width:
2.3
Enter room 1 length:Total house area is 0,000000 m2
```

Comment: Please do not add pictures of text. Instead copy&paste as formatted text into your question. There is no need to show huge empty black space with only a tiny part holding useful information.

Comment: You should always check the return value of `scanf` and other I/O functions.

Comment: Thanks! I have edited it. Just when I thought I was getting used to stackoverflow haha...

Comment: `scanf("%d"` tell the system to read an integer. When it sees something that cannot be a number, like an`'a'` or  a `'.'` it stops. That's how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Yes I am using that for the `if statement` the rest I am using `double`

Comment: Does `printf(" ...%lf...")` really print `0,00000`? With `,` instead of `.`? Does Turkish locale expect you to enter `2,3`?

Comment: WHAT! it works now! thank you so much!. I am so not used to using commas instead of points yet

Comment: Do you think there is a way I could have done it more efficiently?